# Link sem usar a href

Tags: javascript, html, css

Existe alguma maneira de usar links sem a tag `<a href>`.
Por exemplo `<a href="exemplo">exemplo</a>` existe outra forma de fazer isto?

Comment: Você quer esse link seja redirecionado automaticamente, ou o usuário deve clicar sobre ele?

Comment: Qual sera o motivo de não utilizar a propriedade href da tag ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A única alternativa é usando JavaScript, *inline* no HTML ou com auscultador de eventos.

Deves ter em conta que em termos de SEO e semântica a *tag* `<a>` é a correta a usar. Mas se mesmo assim quiseres não usar uma âncora podes usar assim (tendo em conta a estilização do ponteiro do mouse, [como o @Maniero indicou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/101934)):

#### auscultador de evento

HTML

```
<div id="link" data-link="site.com">exemplo</div>
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('link').addEventListener('click', function () {
  var href = this.dataset.link;
  window.location = href;
});
```

#### inline

HTML

```
<div onclick="location.href = 'site.com'">exemplo</div>
```

Comment: Auscultador de evento seria event listener correto ? não teria uma palavra mais usual para colocar ou deveria ser esta mesmo ?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues em portugal é usual, e é uma tradução aceitável para listener. No Brasil a gente usa mais pra quando está no médico :) http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=auscultar

Answer (score 5):

A título de curiosidade pode ser fazer isto:

```
<a id="missionclick" class="moreinfo" style="cursor:pointer;">exemplo</a>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/LinkWithoutHref.html).

Obviamente não há necessidade de evitar o `<a href>`.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4601287/221800).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode realizar o seguinte:

*HTML*

```
<a class="meuClick" style="cursor:pointer;">Aqui</a>
```

Em seu *javascript*:

```
$("a").on('click', '.meuClick', function()
{
   //faça algo
}
```

Utilizando este método, ele reconhece até mesmo se for um link vindo do **DOM** (ou seja dinâmico).

Answer (score 0):

Não muito diferente das respostas **"inline"** já apresentadas mas usando `window.open()`

```html
<a onclick="window.open('https://pt.stackoverflow.com/','_self', 'noopener')" style="cursor:pointer;">SOpt</a>
```

A diferença fica pelo segundo argumento: `_self` para a mesma janela ou `_blank` para abrir em uma nova guia